# signal processing for audio file in python

Tags: audio, aiff

I am tying to do silence detection in uncompressed AIFF audio files. I prefer to do it in Python, but would consider other options if this is super inefficient. The uncompressed files I am dealing with are expected to be 20 MB (maximum size).

I can understand basics of signal processing, but am not an expert in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck! The [aifc](http://docs.python.org/library/aifc.html) library seems to do enough to support the solving of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Language-agnostic pseudo code:

- for each time window (e.g. 10 ms)

  - calculate RMS power in time window
  - silence = RMS power < silence threshold

To calculate RMS power:

- sum_sq = 0
- for each sample in N sample window

  - sum_sq += sample^2
- RMS power = sqrt(sum_sq / N)

You probably also want to add a further layer of detection, e.g. decide that silence = M consecutive silent windows, where M determines how long a silence needs to be before it counts as an actual silence.

Comment: Let me try this. With afic library, I can read a frame at a time (don't think I can read raw bytes) and compute RMS and do the rest.